# Export models as PMML using PySpark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-mllib, apache-spark-ml

Is it possible to export models as PMMLs using PySpark? I know this is possible using Spark. But I did not find any reference in PySpark docs. So does this mean that if I want to do this, I need to write custom code using some third party python PMML library?

Comment: There is not support for PMMLs using pyspark for now.

Comment: @eliasah an you give some insight to second part of my question? "does this mean that if I want to do this, I need to write custom code using some third party python PMML library?"

Comment: probably, I can't give an exact answer on the second part of your question. It's mainly opinion based but this is what I would do.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. If you can post this as an answer I can accept it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is possible to export Apache Spark pipelines to PMML using the [JPMML-SparkML](https://github.com/jpmml/jpmml-sparkml) library. Furthermore, this library is made available for end users in the form of a "Spark Package" by the [JPMML-SparkML-Package](https://github.com/jpmml/jpmml-sparkml-package) project.

Example PySpark code:

```
from jpmml_sparkml import toPMMLBytes
pmmlBytes = toPMMLBytes(sc, df, pipelineModel)
print(pmmlBytes)
```

Comment: Great. Will try this out.

Comment: @user1808924 @SameeraR  have you managed to generate pmml out of PySpark code using mentioned JPMML-SparkML-Package project? I am running into `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Field "label" does not exist.` exception on this line: `pipelineModel = pipeline.fit(df)` This applies both to Scala and PySpark code.